# DataSet changes to sdf local database

Tags: c#, database, dataset, sdf

I created .sdf database in my project.

DataSet for my base was created. So i'm using this DataSet object, and add new rows to tables using DataGridView.

Then I want to save all my changes back to .sdf database.

How I can simply do it? I'm sure there is something for automatically update from DataSet to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `SqlDataAdapter` that has `SqlCommands` set up for each row.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx) for more information on how to use DataAdapters.